# Método compareTo da interface Comparable permite quebra de encapsulamento?

Tags: java, encapsulamento

A classe Estudante tem seus atributos privados e para acessá-los ou modificá-los é necessário o uso dos métodos get e set. Além disso a classe Estudante implementa a interface Comparable.

```
class Estudante implements Comparable<Estudante> {

    private String nome;
    private double nota;

    public Estudante(String nome, double nota) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public double getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(double nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Estudante o) {
        o.nome = "QUEBRA DE ENCAPSULAMENTO";
        return (int) (this.nota - o.getNota());
    }
}
```

No método main da classe principal TesteUniversidade são instanciados 2 objetos da classe Estudante e o método getNome do objeto e2 é chamado antes e depois da comparação de e1 com e2.

Por que é possível quebrar o encapsulamento do atributo nome de e2 dentro do método compareTo de e1?

Veja: https://ideone.com/9H5pna

Comment: Mas quem ta acessando o campo é a propria classe, quebrar encapsulamento é quando um campo é acessivel ao exterior de forma irrestrita.

Comment: Mas está acessando o atributo de uma outra instância, mesmo ambas sendo da mesma classe.

Comment: São duas instancias da mesma classe, podem não ser o mesmo objeto mas ambas conhecem a implementação da outra,  não há violação neste caso.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027139/access-private-field-of-another-object-in-same-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027139/access-private-field-of-another-object-in-same-class)

Comment: @Piovezan Depois de ler as respostas do link acima entendi as vantagens de campos privados terem acesso a nível de classe e não nível de objeto.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas @diegofm e Piovezan.